# Как преобразовать массив в текст и записать его в value

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpstorm, php7, redbeanphp

Есть массив $value9. Если выводить его на экран print_r ($value9) то всё работает так как надо. Но мне нужно все элементы этого массива преобразовать в строку и записать как текст.

Пробовал так, чтобы преобразовать массив в строку

```
$value10 = implode("|", $value9);
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="' . $value10 . '">';
```

Но получаю в поле Array|Array|Array|Array

А мне нужно, чтобы вместо Array был текст

Comment: `var_export($var, true)`   `json_encode($var)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
  $value10 = explode('|', $value9);
  $key;
  foreach ($value10 as $el) { $key .= $key; }
  echo '<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="' . $key . '">';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]